# AutoIT: Download file from IE and save it in mentioned directory

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, autoit

My requirement is to download file from Internet Explorer (version 11) and save it particular location using selenium and AutoIT. Path to save file is given through command line.

Here's my code:

```
; get the handle of main window
Local $windHandle= WinGetHandle("[Class:IEFrame]", "")
Local $winTitle = "[HANDLE:" & $windHandle & "]"

; Select save as option
WinActivate ($winTitle, "")
Send("{F6}")
sleep(500)
Send("{TAB}")
sleep(500)
Send("{DOWN}")
sleep(500)
Send("a")

; Save as dialog
; wait for Save As window
WinWait("Save As")
; activate Save As window
WinActivate("Save As")
ControlFocus("Save As","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Save As","","Edit1",$CmdLine[1])
Sleep(2000)
ControlClick("Save As","","Button2")

===Execution of above code through selenium=====

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\AutoIT\\downloadFile.exe"+" "+"D:\\AutoIT\\abc.pdf");
```

It works but doesn't get saved in particular file instead it saves in default location i.e whichever location "Save As" window shows.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Why you try to work with the unsure Send() -command? AutoIt has the function INetGet() to download files. I've made sometimes a simple to use download function with small GUI to show progress, speed and remaining time. May be its usefull for you:

```
#include <APIShellExConstants.au3>
#include <GuiStatusBar.au3>
#include <InetConstants.au3>
#include <ProgressConstants.au3>

; #FUNCTION# ====================================================================================================================
; Name ..........: _DownloadFile
; Description ...: Downloads a file from a given URL, shows: progress, speed and remaining time.
; Syntax ........: _DownloadFile($_sUrl, $_sFile[, $_sTitle = 'Download'[, $_iWidth = -1[, $_iHeight = -1[, $_iX = -1[, $_iY = -1]]]]])
; Parameters ....: $_sUrl               - The web adress of the file to load.
; ...............: $_sFile              - The path to store this file.
; ..[optional]...: $_sTitle             - Title of the download window. Default is '', = 'Download'.
; ..[optional]...: $_iWidth             - Width of the download window. Default is -1, = 250.
; ..[optional]...: $_iHeight            - Height of the download window. Default is -1, = 75.
; ..[optional]...: $_iX                 - X position of the download window. Default is -1, centered. Other negative value: X px from right, postive values: X px absolute.
; ..[optional]...: $_iY                 - Y position of the download window. Default is -1, centered. Other negative value: Y px from bottom, postive values: Y px absolute.
; Return values .: Success              None
; ...............: Failure              1 and show message box - download has failed or was escaped.
; Author ........: BugFix
; ===============================================================================================================================
Func _DownloadFile($_sUrl, $_sFile, $_sTitle='', $_iWidth=-1, $_iHeight=-1, $_iX=-1, $_iY=-1) ; Pos: -1/-1 = center, -X/-Y = X px from right / Y px from bottom
    $_sTitle = $_sTitle = '' ? 'Download' : $_sTitle
    $_iWidth = $_iWidth = -1 ? 250 : $_iWidth
    $_iHeight = $_iHeight = -1 ? 75 : $_iHeight
    If FileExists($_sFile) Then FileMove($_sFile, $_sFile & '.bak', 1)

    ; Download in background, wait until DL complete - show it in GUI
    Local $iBytesSize, $hDL = GUICreate($_sTitle, $_iWidth, $_iHeight, -1, -1, BitOR(0x00C00000,0x00080000)) ; WS_CAPTION,WS_SYSMENU
    Local $idDL_sum = GUICtrlCreateLabel('0,000 KB', 5, 5, $_iWidth-10, 30, 0x01) ; SS_CENTER
    GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 14, Default, Default, 'Verdana')
    Local $aParts[3] = [75,$_iWidth-75,-1]
    Local $hStatus = _GUICtrlStatusBar_Create($hDL, $aParts)
    _GUICtrlStatusBar_SetMinHeight($hStatus, 25)
    Local $idProgress = GUICtrlCreateProgress(0, $_iHeight-20-26, $_iWidth, 20, $PBS_SMOOTH)
    Local $iTimer = TimerInit()
    ; get absolute window size, move window
    Local $aWin = WinGetPos($hDL)
    Select
        Case $_iX = -1
            $_iX = (@DesktopWidth - $aWin[2]) / 2
        Case $_iX < -1
            $_iX = @DesktopWidth - ($aWin[2] - $_iX)
    EndSelect
    Select
        Case $_iY = -1
            $_iY = (@DesktopHeight - $aWin[3]) / 2
        Case $_iY < -1
            $_iY = @DesktopHeight - ($aWin[3] - $_iY)
    EndSelect
    WinMove($hDL, '', $_iX, $_iY)
    GUISetState()

    Local $iSizeSource = InetGetSize($_sUrl)
    Local $hDownload = InetGet($_sUrl, $_sFile, $INET_FORCERELOAD, $INET_DOWNLOADBACKGROUND)
    _GUICtrlStatusBar_SetText($hStatus, @TAB & _FormatByte($iSizeSource, '', False, 0), 2)

    Local $fEsc = False, $iDL_old = 0, $iDL_diff, $iTimeNeed
    Do
        If TimerDiff($iTimer) >= 1000 Then
            $iBytesSize = InetGetInfo($hDownload, $INET_DOWNLOADREAD)
            GUICtrlSetData($idDL_sum, StringReplace(_FormatByte($iBytesSize), '.', ','))
            GUICtrlSetData($idProgress, Int(($iBytesSize/$iSizeSource)*100))
            $iDL_diff = $iBytesSize - $iDL_old
            $iDL_old = $iBytesSize
            _GUICtrlStatusBar_SetText($hStatus, @TAB & _FormatByte($iDL_diff, '', False, '0') & '/s', 0)
            $iTimeNeed = ($iSizeSource - $iBytesSize) / $iDL_diff
            _GUICtrlStatusBar_SetText($hStatus, @TAB & _FormatSeconds($iTimeNeed), 1)
            $iTimer = TimerInit()
        EndIf
        If GUIGetMsg() = -3 Then
            $fEsc = True
            ExitLoop
        EndIf
    Until InetGetInfo($hDownload, $INET_DOWNLOADCOMPLETE)
    _GUICtrlStatusBar_SetText($hStatus, '', 0)
    _GUICtrlStatusBar_SetText($hStatus, '', 1)

    ; get info about DL file
    Local $aData = InetGetInfo($hDownload)
    If @error Or $fEsc Then
        FileDelete($_sFile)
        Local $sTmp = $fEsc ? 'escaped' : 'failed'
        GUICtrlSetData($idDL_sum, 'Download ' & $sTmp & '!')
        Return SetError(1,0,MsgBox(262192, 'Error', 'The Download has ' & $sTmp & '.'))
    Else
        GUICtrlSetData($idDL_sum, StringReplace(_FormatByte($iBytesSize), '.', ','))
        GUICtrlSetData($idProgress, 100)
        Sleep(500)
        GUICtrlSetData($idDL_sum, 'Download finished.')
    EndIf
    InetClose($hDownload)
    GUIDelete($hDL)
EndFunc  ;==>_DownloadFile


; #FUNCTION# ====================================================================================================================
; Name ..........: _FormatSeconds
; Description ...: Returns a given value of seconds in the format
; ...............:        <24h: "hh:mm:ss", >=24h: "x d / hh:mm:ss h"
; Syntax ........: _FormatSeconds($_sec)
; Parameters ....: $_sec                - The number of seconds.
; Return values .: The formatted string.
; Author ........: BugFix
; ===============================================================================================================================
Func _FormatSeconds($_sec)
    Return ( $_sec < 60 ? StringFormat('00:00:%02u', $_sec) : _
             $_sec < 60*60 ? StringFormat('00:%02u', Floor($_sec/60)) & ':' & _
                    StringFormat('%02u', Mod($_sec,60)) : _
             $_sec < 60*60*24 ? StringFormat('%02u', Floor($_sec/3600)) & ':' & _
                    StringFormat('%02u', Floor(Mod($_sec,3600)/60)) & ':' & _
                    StringFormat('%02u', Mod(Mod($_sec,3600),60)) : _
             ( $_sec = 86400 ? "24:00:00" : Floor($_sec/86400) & ' d / ' & _
                    StringFormat('%02u', Floor(Mod($_sec,86400)/3600)) & ':' & _
                    StringFormat('%02u', Floor(Mod(Mod($_sec,86400),3600)/60)) & ':' & _
                    StringFormat('%02u', Mod(Mod(Mod($_sec,86400),3600),60)) & ' h') )
EndFunc  ;==>_FormatSeconds

; #FUNCTION# ====================================================================================================================
; Name ..........: _FormatByte
; Description ...: Formats a given value of bytes with highest or given unit, optional as structure with all units
; Parameters ....: $_iByte    The value of bytes to format
; ...............: $_sUnit    (Default = '', unit of highest value) or count of given unit (TB, GB, MB, KB, Byte)
; ...............: $_fStruct  Returns a structure with .TB .GB .MB .KB .Byte (Default = False)
; ...............: $_sDigit   Number of decimal digits (Default = '3') as string!
; Return values .: The formatted string or the structure.
; Author ........: BugFix
; ===============================================================================================================================
Func _FormatByte($_iByte, $_sUnit='', $_fStruct=False, $_sDigit='3')
    Local Static $aByte[5][2] = [[0x10000000000],[0x40000000],[0x100000],[0x400],[0x1]]
    Local Static $tBytes = DllStructCreate('int TB;int GB;int MB;int KB;int Byte;')
    Local Static $aUnit[5] = ['TB','GB','MB','KB','Byte']
    Local $iModulo = $_iByte, $iHighest = 4
    For $i = 0 To 3
        $aByte[$i][1] = $iModulo >= $aByte[$i][0] ? Floor($iModulo/$aByte[$i][0]) : 0
        $iModulo = $aByte[$i][1] > 0 ? Mod($iModulo,$aByte[$i][0]) : $iModulo
        $iHighest = $aByte[$i][1] > 0 ? ($i < $iHighest ? $i : $iHighest) : $iHighest
    Next
    $aByte[4][1] = $iModulo
    If $_fStruct Then
        $tBytes.TB   = $aByte[0][1]
        $tBytes.GB   = $aByte[1][1]
        $tBytes.MB   = $aByte[2][1]
        $tBytes.KB   = $aByte[3][1]
        $tBytes.Byte = $aByte[4][1]
        Return $tBytes
    EndIf
    $_sUnit = StringInStr('TB GB MB KB Byte', $_sUnit) ? $_sUnit : ''
    $_sUnit = $_sUnit = '' ? $aUnit[$iHighest] : $_sUnit
    Local $iUserUnit = Floor(StringInStr('TB GB MB KB Byte', $_sUnit)/3)
    If Number($_sDigit) < 0 Then $_sDigit = '0'
    Local $sFormat = '%.' & $_sDigit & 'f %s'
    Return StringFormat($sFormat, $_iByte/$aByte[$iUserUnit][0], $aUnit[$iUserUnit])
EndFunc  ;==>_FormatByte
```

Answer (score 0):

> It works but doesn't get saved in particular file instead it saves in
>   default location i.e whichever location "Save As" window shows.

I took me a while but finally figured it out for my project, hope someone could benefit from this. It turns out the Address Bar for folder path is a combo of (Toolbar buttons and an Edit box). I don't know the actual structures but the way I visualizing it is; Edit box is nested inside ToolbarWindow32. When address bar (ToolbarWindow32) is clicked to Manually input your own Path then Edit box is activated. Imagine ToolbarWindow32 is the parent and Edit box is the child. Anyone with the knowledge please shed some light into this.

Here is a working example with different ways of accomplishing the same thing.

```
    #include <GuiToolbar.au3>
    #Include <File.au3>


    TestChangeSaveAsAddress()

    Func TestChangeSaveAsAddress()

        Run('Notepad.exe')
        WinWaitActive('Untitled - Notepad')
        Send('new line.')
        Send('^s')


        Local $AddressPath = 'K:\_DOC\_TEXT'
        Local $aFileName = 'New File.txt'
        ClipPut($AddressPath)                    ;for  Option 1

        Local $SaveAsTitle = '[CLASS:#32770; TITLE:Save As]'


    # I.a

        ;get 'Save As' window handle
        Local $hWnd = WinWaitActive($SaveAsTitle, '&Save', 10)

    # I.b

        ;get Address Bar handle for $AddressPath
        Local $hTollbars = ControlGetHandle($hWnd, 'Address', '[CLASSNN:ToolbarWindow324]')


    # II - IMPORTANT: Address Bar must be infocus in order to activate Edit2 to set $AddressPath in step (IV)
           ;Option 2 or 3 is highly recommended


        # ;Option 1 - Select ToolbarWindow32 - Address Bar (work around -not recomended)
        #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;~         ControlFocus($hTollbars, 'Address', '')
    ;~         ControlSend($hTollbars, 'Address', '','{SPACE}')
    ;~         Send('^v{ENTER}')

        # ;Option 2 - Select ToolbarWindow32 - Address Bar (same as Option 3)
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------
             ControlCommand($hTollbars, "Address", "", "SendCommandID", 1280)

        # ;Option 3 - Select ToolbarWindow32 - Address Bar (same as Option 2)
        #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;~         ControlCommand($hWnd, "Address", "ToolbarWindow324", "SendCommandID", 1280)

        # ;Option 4 - Select ToolbarWindow32 - Address Bar (mouse pointer also relocated)
        #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;~        _GUICtrlToolbar_ClickIndex($hTollbars, -1,'Left',True,1,0)

        # ;Option 5 - Select ToolbarWindow32 - Address Bar (this simulate as Run, NOT RunWait if your project required it - NOT Recommended)
        #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;~      Run(@AutoItExe & ' /AutoIt3ExecuteLine "ControlCommand ( hwnd(' & $hWnd & '),'''', hwnd(' & $hTollbars & '), ''SendCommandID'', 1280 )"')


    # III
            ;check if path $AddressPath exists
            If Not FileExists($AddressPath) Then DirCreate($AddressPath)

    # IV
            ;set new path
            ControlSetText($hWnd, "Address", 'Edit2', $AddressPath)
    ;~         ControlFocus($hTollbars,'Address','')


    # V
            ;commit new Path
            ControlSend($hWnd, "Address", 'Edit2','{ENTER}')

    # VI
            ;set new file name
            ControlSetText($hWnd, "Namespace", "Edit1", $aFileName)
            ControlFocus($hWnd,'Namespace','Edit1')

    # VII
            ;allow manual keypress {SPACE} or {ENTER} to save/cancel
    ;~         ControlFocus($hWnd,'&Save','Button1')
    ;~         ControlFocus($hWnd,'Cancel','Button2')

    # VIII
            ;auto click save/cancel
    ;~         ControlClick($hWnd,"&Save", 'Button1','Left')
    ;~         ControlClick($hWnd,"Cancel", 'Button2','Left')


    # IX
        #--------------------------------------------------
        # ---OR--- skip all above steps and use this work around
        #--------------------------------------------------
    ;~     ControlSetText($hWnd, "Namespace", "Edit1", $AddressPath&'\'&$aFileName)

    EndFunc
```